# Difference between executing np.random.seed() locally and globally/

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know difference between executing `np.random.seed()` inside of a function and outside of it. (same seed)
For instance...

```
np.random.seed(1)
def coin_toss():
    if np.random.randint(0,2) == 1:
        return 'HEAD'
    else:
        return 'TAIL'
for value in range (10): 
    print(coin_toss())
```

The output of this is

```
HEAD
HEAD
TAIL
TAIL
HEAD
HEAD
HEAD
HEAD
HEAD
TAIL
```

On the other hand, when I put np.random.seed(1) inside of the function, I got a different output.

```
def coin_toss2():
    np.random.seed(1)
    if np.random.randint(0,2) == 1:
        return 'HEAD'
    else:
        return 'TAIL'
for value in range(10):
    print(coin_toss2())
```

the output of this is

```
HEAD
HEAD
HEAD
HEAD
HEAD
HEAD
HEAD
HEAD
HEAD
HEAD
```

Since the seed, 1, is same in both of the examples, I expected that I got same results. What are differences which cause the difference of the outputs ? Could someone explain this ? 
I just understood that there is also a concept of global and local in random state. However, I still don't comprehend why this difference happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Seed* is the value used to generate a pseudo number. The current seed value is the previous value generated by random. If no previous seed is available, Numpy uses the system time as default.

So, once set up a seed and never update it manually, the following random operations always generate upon previous values. That's what your first code does.

```
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.randint(0, 10)
np.random.randint(0, 10)
np.random.randint(0, 10)
```

```
5
0
3
```

As in your second code, you reset the seed value every time before you call the random. It reasonably generates the same value because their seeds are all the same.

```
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.randint(0, 10)
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.randint(0, 10)
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.randint(0, 10)
```

```
5
5
5
```

Comment: Thank you  so much. So, in your first code, first ```np.random.randint(0,10)``` use seed of 0. Then, the second ```np.random.randint(0,10)``` uses a seed created by the first ```np.random.randint(0,10)```?

Comment: Not the return value, but some internal values (aka random state).

Comment: so a reason why I get a same result as yours when I run your first code is that the current seed is ultimately based on the first seed, 0. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, the same seed outputs the same value.

Comment: I appreciate your time for this. It makes very clear now.